# Repeat var with dynamic value PHP

Tags: php, html

I've a certain amount of posts, each post contains a modal (sort of a popup) the HTML of this modal is in the $html[] var. The code below works well except as you can see it is not dynamic.

**What i've tried:**

```
$post_count = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]; // i've to mannualy add a number according to the number of posts
$counter = 1;
foreach($number_of_modals as $modal){
    echo $html[$counter];
    $counter++;
}
```

**Explanation of what i need to accomplish**

```
$post_count; // if this val is 3 for example

echo $html[1];
echo $html[2];
echo $html[3];
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem now?

Comment: Id like to repeat the `$html` as many times as the post_count

Comment: get the no. of posts & push the values in an array by array_push in loop.it will be dynamic e.g. no of posts=3 then foreach loop will be used in pushing the value in $post_count array.

Comment: @Paul Why don't you do a simple for loop?

Comment: Thanks Rizier123 i think that's the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul suggested, use either a for loop, or a while loop:

```
$post_count = 3;
$counter = 0;
while ($counter <= $post_count) {
    echo $html[$counter];
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I accepted it as the best answer, it works how i wanted it. Excuse me if the question was a little bit unclear

Comment: The "Explanation of what i need to accomplish" part pretty much explained what should've been the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one?

```
foreach($number_of_modals as $key => $modal){
    echo $html[$key];
}
```

Since you haven't given the structure of $number_of_modals array, I assumed it's like the $html array

```
$modal = array('1', 'abc', 'etc');
```

Which translates to `$modal = array(0 => '1', 1 => 'abc', 2 => 'etc');`

In that foreach each $key corresponds to 0,1,2 which gives the $counter you are looking for.

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Comment: @TheThom Sure thing I added the explanation. You are welcome Paul.